# Tcl/TK Stopwatch Time tracker

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a task tracking program for my job. It is modified from [stopwatch](http://expect.sourceforge.net/stopwatch/).

It's basic function is to visually keep track of the time each task takes, record it into a text file and zero the clock. [Here](http://oi51.tinypic.com/t5pvkj.jpg) is a screenshot of the program as it sits now.

The buttons and labels are placed using grid like so:

```
grid .laplabel .laptime .laprecord .lapzero
grid configure .laplabel      -sticky e
grid configure .laptime       -sticky ns
grid .lap2label .lap2time .lap2record .lap2zero
grid configure .lap2label      -sticky e
grid configure .lap2time       -sticky ns
grid .lap3label .lap3time .lap3record .lap3zero
```

etc...

Each press of the record button invokes .laprecord and .lapzero like so:

```
button .laprecord -text "record" -command {
    record L TEST$time(lap)
set time(lap) [timeformat 0]
set time(lstart) [now]
}
proc lapzr {} {
    .laprecord invoke
    .lapzero invoke
}
```

So, the gui is becoming unwieldy with even the twelve entries now present, and I have approximately fifteen more to add. What I envision is that all of the entries which are now arranged using grid will be instead arranged into a single drop down menu.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [tktable](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1877). It appears to be designed for this sort of tabular data, and IIRC it can be bound to an array so inserting more rows should be simple.